# Is it possible to pass output from one connector to another in Power Automate?

Tags: power-automate

I am new to Power Automate. This seems like a trivial item, but I am having a hard time finding a straight answer. I created a custom connector in Power Automate to retrieve some data from an API. I would like to take the result of that data and pass it to another connector. The connector for posting something into Microsoft Teams to be exact. Is this possible? I don't see any option on these connectors for passing variables/data/parameter/arguments etc.